# Handling Gestures in default Honeycomb browser with RaphelJS

Tags: raphael, android-3.0-honeycomb, gesture

I've been trying to get gestures to work in a webpage using RaphaelJS in Honeycomb's default browser (Motorola Xoom, v3.2), but I'm not seeing any gesture events firing. They work OK on iPad in Safari.

I've also tried to detect more than one finger and do my own implementation, but for every new finger press while another is held, I get touchend before the next touchbegin, so I can never tell if more than one finger is being held.

I've seen a number of posts around that say gestures are not possible, but if you visit maps.google.com, pinch zoom gestures seem to work OK. How is Google making this work?